# RX Java android for retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm new to rx java, so can you help with it. I have simple retrofit implementation and i'm using it to get data about radio. I need to get this data every 10 seconds. The only way i know to do it is using Service with AlarmManager, but i don't like it. How can i do it using rx java? Can i get data every 10 seconds.
Here is the code of retrofit implementation

```
public class ApiProvider {
    public static final String PRODUCTION_API_URL = "http://radio.somesite.org";
    static final int DISK_CACHE_SIZE = (int) MEGABYTES.toBytes(50);
    private static ApiProvider instance;
    private Application application;

    private ApiProvider( ) {
        this.application = CApplication.getApplication();
    }

    public static ApiProvider getInstance() {
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;
        else {
            instance = new ApiProvider();
            return instance;
        }

    }

    public static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient(Application app) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(10, SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(10, SECONDS);
        client.setWriteTimeout(10, SECONDS);

        // Install an HTTP cache in the application cache directory.
        File cacheDir = new File(app.getCacheDir(), "http");
        Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
        client.setCache(cache);

        return client;
    }

    private RestAdapter getRestAdapter() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeConverter())
                .create();
        OkHttpClient client = createOkHttpClient(application);

        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint(PRODUCTION_API_URL);

        return new RestAdapter.Builder() //
                .setClient(new OkClient(client)) //
                .setEndpoint(endpoint) //
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)) //
                .build();
    }



    private RadioLiveInfoService getRadioInfo() {
        return getRestAdapter().create(RadioLiveInfoService.class);
    }

    private RadioWeekInfoService getRadioWeek() {
        return getRestAdapter().create(RadioWeekInfoService.class);
    }

    public void getRadioInfo(Type type, final CallbackInfoListener listener) {
        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void success(Object o, Response response) {
                try {
                    LiveInfo liveInfo = (LiveInfo) o;
                    listener.dataLoaded(liveInfo, true);
                    Log.d("Success", response.toString());
                } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                listener.dataLoaded(new LiveInfo(), false);
                Log.e("Error", retrofitError.toString());
            }
        };

        getRadioInfo().commits(type, callback);
    }

    public void getRadioWeekInfo(final CallbackWeekListener listener) {
        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void success(Object o, Response response) {
                try {
                    WeekInfo weekInfo = (WeekInfo) o;
                    listener.dataLoaded(weekInfo, true);
                    Log.d("Success", response.toString());
                } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                listener.dataLoaded(new WeekInfo(), false);
                Log.e("Error", retrofitError.toString());
            }
        };

        getRadioWeek().commits(callback);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to use `RxJava` why are you not using the `Observable<T>` API of Retrofit? You could then use `interval` or `timer` (I forget which operator it is) and ta-dah. That's the route, anyways, but I've never gone there before, I just saw the street signs.

Comment: ok. i'll try. I don't know what is Observable. Is it something like a pattern or what? It's like you can call the method and when it will finish getting the data of the Observable<T> will change dynamically?

Comment: Look here, it does exactly what you are describing: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84304/using-a-subject-to-trigger-a-music-list-to-reload. Also, have a look under the header "SYNCHRONOUS VS. ASYNCHRONOUS VS. OBSERVABLE" at http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: How are you planning to use RxJava if you don't know what an Observable is? That is pretty much the heart and soul of Rx. Literally everything is about transforming Observables into other Observables using operators on Observables. Then binding it to an observer that is listening to them on a given scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it to work this way. Still i need to understand how to do it with composit subscription.

```
RadioLiveInfoObservableService radioLiveInfoObservableService=ApiProvider.getInstance().getRadioObserverInfo();
radioLiveInfoObservableService.commits(Type.INTERVAL)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError(trendingError)
        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<LiveInfo>empty()).subscribe(new Action1<LiveInfo>() {
    @Override
    public void call(LiveInfo liveInfo) {
        List<Current> currents=new ArrayList<Current>();
        currents.add(liveInfo.getCurrent());
        adapter.currentShows=currents;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using it this way

```
fun getEventDetails(eventId: Long) : MutableLiveData<Response> {
    Log.d("Retrofit", "Get event detail")
    compositeDisposable.add(useCase.getEvents()
            .repeatWhen {
                return@repeatWhen it.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //Repeat every 10 seconds
            }
            .repeatUntil {
                return@repeatUntil repeat //Boolean
            }
            .map(this::parseResponse)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                dashboardResponse.postValue(Response().success(it))
            }, {
                Timber.d(it.message)
                dashboardResponse.postValue(Response().error(it.getRetrofitErrorMessage()))
            })
    )

    return dashboardResponse

}
```

And API Method is :

```
 @GET("events")
fun getEvents(): Observable<String>
```